# wget options to get output straight to R

Tags: r, wget

I have a wget_string and commands made as follows:

```
wget_string <- paste("wget --user=" , u_name , " --password=", p_word,     " ", my_urls,' -qO ', file_name,   sep="")
 system(wget_string)
 readLines(file_name)
```

Which works, but then I have to use readLines() to read the file into R. I would like to run the command so that file is available directly in R, without being saved to the hard disk and then loaded from it.

I'm hoping to save resources by loading the file straight into R from the web. Can't use readlines from the beginning because of the secure server. What are the options for this?

Comment: Note there's a security issue with putting passwords on command lines like this - they can be read by anyone else on the system. Better to put them in .wgetrc (read the wget help for more).

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. I was worried about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An `intern=TRUE` parameter the `system` function has. Capture the output from the command it does. Use the force, and the right options to `wget` to print to stdout:

```
> wget_string="wget -qO- http://www.google.com"
> s = system(wget_string,intern=TRUE)
```

If your returned data is a CSV file, `textConnection` you can use, feed it to `read.csv` you can.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `-O -` option of `wget` you set the output to the `standar output` (writing directly on the screen). In this way you can read directly from the output of the wget command.

E.g.

```
 wget -O - http: //www.address.com
```

Will download the web page and print it directly to the `standard output`. So you can directly read the output of the `system(wget_string)`.

From the `wget` man page:

> -O file
>          --output-document=file
>              The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.  **If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output**, disabling link conversion.  (Use
>              ./- to print to a file literally named -.)